# Deploy C# Winforms with SQL Server database

Tags: .net, winforms, deployment, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a Winforms app and a SQL Server 2008 R2 database (offline desktop app). I want to turn it into an executable so I can run it on other PC's.

I tried publishing it with ClickOnce but some functionality doesn't work and some label/picture placement is even different (because I think the database isn't included in the resources?) Checking other similar post I have chosen embedded resource in my `dataset.xsd` but didn't work.

How/where should I "add" the database? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Consider using an embedded database like [SQLServer CE](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/01/11/vs-2010-sp1-and-sql-ce.aspx). It is a free database that you can use for building Windows desktop 
applications with a small footprint. It has some limitations: no stored procedures, no views, no triggers, no blob columns but it is a set of dll files loaded by your application and doesn't require any installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your Winforms App - you should create a setup project in Visual Studio - it will create an installer with an exe file and resources, which you need.

I don't understand the part with the database. Do you want to integrate the XSD (XML Schema Definition) file in the installer or integrate an offline database like SQLite or Access?

Comment: I will mark this as answer. Never heard of setup project, will look more into. Regarding the database, I was curious as to how to include it into the installer so that the client has access to the data; I assume it's exactly the same as including other files?